# Difference dot(.) and underscore(_) between block name

Tags: layout, blocks

As i go through editing/creating theme, i find that at some places magento block names are with underscore(_) or dot(.), e.g

```
<block name="paypal.partner.right.logo"template="paypal/partner/logo.phtml"/>
```

and somewhere it is

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

It get confusing, why magento has . syntax and somewhere _.

How does one remove a block name which has following syntax

```
<block type="catalog/product_price_template" name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the two. However it is better to stick to one for better code style. The more frequently used one is with the dot.

To remove the block, you can reference its name in the Remove tag in your own local.xml like this:

```
<remove name="catalog_product_price_template" />
```